# Linux desktop software to create photo albums

Tags: linux, photobooks

I am wanting to design a photo album/photo book, in which I put together different photos, some text, etc. and this become a multi-page document. I very much enjoy [Canva](https://www.canva.com/create/photo-books/) which has useful tools such as dragging and dropping, easy swapping out of photos, resizing, and many good-looking templates. However I am looking for an offline, open source tool.

When I search for Linux software to do similar things, I mostly find tools that do "photo management" (tagging and tracking of files), or "photo editing" (modifying individual images). Maybe I am not using the right search terms.

Are there any available programs to create photo albums on Linux?

Comment: I’d recommend asking this on the software recommendations SE site.

Comment: Ah thanks. Should I somehow migrate this question?

Comment: Probably, but I don’t know how.

Comment: I too run Linux, but limiting yourself to an offline tool may not make sense unless you plan on printing and binding the album yourself. If not, you then have the issue of generating a compatible output from your offline tool for a printer. I think you'll find it easier and maybe even cheaper using an online system that will also produce your album. There are many out there; one I used and was happy with is ZNO.

Answer (score 3):

> ...which has useful tools such as dragging and dropping, easy swapping out of photos, resizing, and many good-looking templates.

This sounds like a subset of functions that desktop publishing software, such as [Adobe InDesign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_InDesign), offers.

When I search for "indesign alternatives linux" I find [this page](https://www.ionos.com/digitalguide/websites/web-design/free-alternatives-to-adobe-indesign/) which lists [Scribus](https://www.scribus.net/) as the first alternative.

It seems to match what you're looking for:

- it's [offline](https://www.scribus.net/downloads/stable-branch/)
- it's [opensource](https://www.scribus.net/contribute/)
- [templates are available online](https://www.scribus-templates.net/)

  - here's a template for a [photobook](https://www.scribus-templates.net/templates/photobook)
  - there is a [wiki page](https://wiki.scribus.net/canvas/Photo_Albums) on photo albums

Comment: I have used Scribus generated pdf files to create several photobooks via blurb, which listed detailed requirements on their website. Whilst setting it up was not  easy and though Scribus is slowly improving, there is a lot of desk top publishing terminology and methodology to get your head around. It is doable though and I was pleased with the results.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can do it with Inkscape? I am not sure if it will do what you need but alternativeto.net has it listed as a recommended alternative to Canva.

I have used it for vector graphics and enjoy the interface.